# Google Maps API Passing Variables to the InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code that loops through an array of markers;

The array of places:

```
var map_markers = [['Windsor Road, Salisbury, SP2 7NF <br/> 2nd Line', 'Windsor Road, Salisbury,', 1],['Bishopdown Road, Salisbury, SP1 3DT <br/> 2nd Line', 'Bishopdown Road, Salisbury,', 2],['Gainsborough Close, Salisbury, SP2 9HD <br/> 2nd Line', 'Gainsborough Close, Salisbury,', 3],['Montgomery Gardens, Salisbury, SP2 7UQ <br/> 2nd Line', 'Montgomery Gardens, Salisbury,', 4],['Manor Court, Salisbury, SP1 1LN <br/> 2nd Line', 'Manor Court, Salisbury,', 5],];
```

Obvioulsly all of the above need Geocoding so that I can place a pin for each on the map, I have built the following function for this:

```
function init_map(map_id, center_address, markers) {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': center_address, 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 

         //Init Map Options
         var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }

         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_id), mapOptions);

         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         var marker, i;

         for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  

            var marker_address = markers[i][1];
            var marker_content = markers[i][0];

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': marker_address , 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) { 

             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(marker_content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }

                    }) (marker, i)); 

                } else {
                    alert("There was a issue getting the property information.")
                }
            });
         }

      } else {

        alert("Unable to find address: " + status);

      }

  });
}
```

With the above code the markers are placed correctly on the map and when I click a marker the infoWindow does appear, however, it seems to be getting stuck on the looping and only displays the final array element content on all of the markers. Can anyone recommend a fix?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're creating `marker_content` within your loop, but your event listener function will only know about the final value of that.  Here's a stab at how I'd write this:

```
...
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    var marker_address = markers[i][1];
    var marker_content;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': marker_address , 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
                map: map
            });

            marker_content = markers[i][0];

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, marker_content);
        } else {
            alert("There was a issue getting the property information.")
        }
    });
}
...

// new global function, NOT nested in init_map
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code that I use to sort all this out.  It has more advanced infobox settings so you may not be interested in that.  but note my var markers and spinner up. This is just for the marker segment of your code...

```
var data = { "count": 10785236,
 "locationstuff": [{"photo_id": 27932, "photo_title": "Atardecer en Embalse", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/27932", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/27932.jpg", "longitude": -64.404945, "latitude": -32.202924, "width": 500, "height": 375, "upload_date": "25 June 2006", "owner_id": 4483, "owner_name": "Miguel Coranti", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/4483"}
,
{"photo_id": 522084, "photo_title": "In Memoriam Antoine de Saint Exupéry", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/522084", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/522084.jpg", "longitude": 17.470493, "latitude": 47.867077, "width": 500, "height": 350, "upload_date": "21 January 2007", "owner_id": 109117, "owner_name": "Busa Péter", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/109117"}
,
{"photo_id": 1578881, "photo_title": "Rosina Lamberti,Sunset,Templestowe , Victoria, Australia", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/1578881", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/1578881.jpg", "longitude": 145.141754, "latitude": -37.766372, "width": 500, "height": 474, "upload_date": "01 April 2007", "owner_id": 140796, "owner_name": "rosina lamberti", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/140796"}
,
{"photo_id": 97671, "photo_title": "kin-dza-dza", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/97671", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/97671.jpg", "longitude": 30.785408, "latitude": 46.639301, "width": 500, "height": 375, "upload_date": "09 December 2006", "owner_id": 13058, "owner_name": "Kyryl", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/13058"}
,
{"photo_id": 25514, "photo_title": "Arenal", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/25514", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/25514.jpg", "longitude": -84.693432, "latitude": 10.479372, "width": 500, "height": 375, "upload_date": "17 June 2006", "owner_id": 4112, "owner_name": "Roberto Garcia", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/4112"}
,
{"photo_id": 57823, "photo_title": "Maria Alm", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/57823", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/57823.jpg", "longitude": 12.900009, "latitude": 47.409968, "width": 500, "height": 333, "upload_date": "05 October 2006", "owner_id": 8060, "owner_name": "Norbert MAIER", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/8060"}
]}

var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
    spinnerUp(i);
    }

        function spinnerUp() {

            var data_mapper = data.locationstuff[i];

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data_mapper.latitude,data_mapper.longitude);

            var boxText = "<div class='mapLocationBox'>";
                boxText += "<h2>" + data_mapper.title + "</h2>" + "<p>" + data_mapper.address + "<br>" + data_mapper.city + ", " + data_mapper.zip + "</p>";
                boxText += "</div>";

            switch (data_mapper.iconSpecial)
                {
                case 0:
                  var iconColorSpecial = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png";
                  break;
                case 1:
                  var iconColorSpecial = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";
                  break;
                }

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,icon:iconColorSpecial});

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                    content: boxText
                                                    ,disableAutoPan: false
                                                    ,maxWidth: 0
                                                    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)            
                                                    ,zIndex: null
                                                    ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                                                    ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                                                    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                                                    ,isHidden: false
                                                    ,pane: "floatPane"
                                                    ,enableEventPropagation: false});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map, this);});
        markers.push(marker);       
        }
```

I have a file that feed this the addresses.  It can be dynamic or static.

I also have the geolocation stuff figured out before I spin the locations through my loop.

This method could help you refactor your approach.

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: thanks for the code sample, i will give this a go this afternoon, I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: My pleasure.  Google Maps is tough for the first 20 times you implement it, then it gets easier. :)

Comment: Hi Frank, sorry but I am still having issues with/without your code or the code here :/

Comment: Ok, I saw this earlier.  I am considering the problem while juggling work.  I'll get back to you later one way or another.